# How can I trigger a remote form to submit on Enter (Rails6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a challenging situation where I have comment form with textarea and a Comment button but I want to submit the comment on Enter rather than the user having to click the button.

This is further complicated by the fact that it is a nested comments structure so at any point in time there may be **more than one Comment form on the page**.

I have tried looking at other examples but so far either the form does not submit (when I use requestSubmit, or if I try trigger('submit') or trigger('submit.rails') it submits as HTML and not JS.

My form looks like so:

```
<%= form_for [commentable, Comment.new], remote: true do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control comment", style: "width: 100%;", rows: "1",
        placeholder: "Add your comments" %>
      <%= f.submit 'Send', class: "form-control btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mb-2 comment" %>
<% end %>
```

And my javascript (in javascript/packs/application.js) currently looks like:

```
  $('textarea.comment').on('keyup keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
      $('form').trigger('submit.rails')
     }
  });
```

(I've tried other variants, as mentioned).

I've also added some other includes at the top of my application.js per other examples:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

--

To clarify yes this is Rails 6 and yes a key press does trigger correctly as verified by `console.log`s which I've removed for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Are u running Rails 6+ ? In that case you should switch to rails_ujs. jquery was dropped as a dependency. However as for your question I'm not sure why it doesn't work...when you put a breakpoint inside your js event handle does it actually reach there?

Comment: If I have understood it correctly you are saying you may have multiple forms on the DOM at the same time so how would `$('form').trigger('submit.rails')` work? You want to submit single form only right? So may be finding the `form` using `$(this).parents`. (Not related to your question directly)

Comment: Addiitionally if you are using turbolinks in your application then the code will not work after the inital page load. Turbolinks replaces the page content with ajax and you're binding the handler directly to the elements you're querying. Use `$('body').on('textarea.comment', 'keyup keypress', function(event) { ... });` to create a delegated event handler instead.

Comment: @deep you don't need to use `$(this).parents` - you can just use `$(this.form)`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

Comment: Clarified a couple of points in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Try triggering a click on the submit button which should trigger [the Rails UJS event handler](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2bbb519482dbc7969321719cb515216cf1515bfc/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/features/remote.coffee#L74) indirectly:

```
// Use a delegated handler for compatiblity with Turbolinks
$(document).on('textarea.comment', 'keyup keypress', function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
    $(this.form).find("input[type='submit']").click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry I don't know where $(body) comes from but I get an error if I use it.

Comment: Ironically this text box doesn't let me edit apparently - the second part of my statement was: 

Also when I replace it with my original selector statement ` $('textarea.comment')` it does sometimes trigger the button click but seems sporadic.

Comment: The "erratic" behavior is really to be expected. With turbolinks your JS is evaluated once when the page loads and it then replaces the page content with ajax. So the event handler in your question will only work on the initial page load if at all since its not guarenteed that the elements are ready.

Comment: And sorry it should be `$(document)` and not `$(body)`. This adds the handler to the document itself and catches the event as it bubbles up the DOM. Since the event handlers are not attached directly to the elements it won't break if the page contents are replaced.

Comment: Hi Max, it's a remote form and submitting the new comment replaces /all the comments and the form/ with new versions (just in case other people have commented in the mean time). Does the turbo-links issue exist in this case?

Comment: Yes. Its the same since you're replacing the contents with Ajax. Your handler is attached to the elements that where there when the page loaded. If you add new elements they do not have that event handler attached. The solution is [event delegation](https://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/#:~:text=Event%20delegation%20is%20an%20event,occurring%20on%20it's%20descendant%20elements.).

Comment: Okay learning a lot but I feel I'm already doing this?
My selector is inside `$(document).on('turbolinks:load',function() { `
If I try to use a second `$(document)` inside that it doesn't trigger. Only my first format triggers.

Comment: If you're using a delegated event handler you don't want to wrap it in a `'turbolinks:load'` event handler. Doing so will add the handler over and over every time the page is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Okay for better or for worse this is working:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load',function() {
  $('#comments_container').on('keyup keypress', 'textarea', function(event) {    
    if (event.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
      event.preventDefault();
      let target = event.target; // target is the textarea
      $(target.form).find("input[type=submit]").trigger('click')
    }
  });

...

});
```